# Magento 2.4.2 : Add to Cart button is disabled on listing page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, catalog

In Magento 2.4.2 "Add to Cart" button is disabled in template and is being enabled using js post initialization

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<button type="submit" 
    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" 
    class="action tocart primary" 
    disabled>
    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
</button>
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

```
_create: function () {
    if (this.options.bindSubmit) {
        this._bindSubmit();
    }
    $(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Can anyone help me with reason behind this approach? It wasn't there in Magento 2.4.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is the commit with the change to the product list template and js. Issue was MC-36548: Invalid Form Key error when adding to cart before page full… https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/95859dc036a6076423f30409f224a6b5d6f5ac84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there was an issue with invalid form key errors when add to cart was clicked before the page was fully loaded.

The change ensures that the add to cart button is enabled only when the page is fully loaded and `catalog-add-to-cart.js` has been processed.

The commit from August 2020 can be seen here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/95859dc036a6076423f30409f224a6b5d6f5ac84

This change will cause problems if you are extending `catalog-add-to-cart.js` in your custom theme or modules. You should update your custom/extended js to activate the add to cart button.

```
$(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file path

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Click `ctrl+F` and search for `action tocart primary`

```
<button type="submit" title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"class="action tocart primary">
<span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>
</span></button>
```

Just replace button tag with this code and run (As you mentioned in comments disabled is there just remove or replace the button tag with above code)

For ubuntu

```
sudo rm -rf generated/* var/* && sudo bin/magento cache:flush
```

For windows

```
rm -rf generated/* var/* && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: There is a reason why they have changed this in 2.4.2 - probably best not to simply change the button...